# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I created free account on twilio and I get this generated phone no

`+1 (201) 345-7453`

when I tried to use this phone # in the code

```
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create("+1 (201) 345-7453", "myphone # here", "Jenny please?! I love you <3", array());
echo $sms->sid;
```

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The From phone number +12013457453 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account`

Comment: Everything looks right to me.  I'd shoot an email over to help@twilio.com an our support team can dig into whats going on with this number.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem... If I produce an error it breaks the app...

Comment: Could you solve the problem and how?

Comment: Nope, still having trouble

Answer (score 3):

The "From" property becomes "from" when you call the create() method because of

```
abstract class Services_Twilio_InstanceResource extends Services_Twilio_Resource {
    ...
    $decamelizedParams = $this->client->createData($this->uri, $params);
    $this->updateAttributes($decamelizedParams);
```

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/Twilio/InstanceResource.php#L31

The "SMS Message" resource has been deprecated by Twilio so don't expect a fix. I recommend you just move over to the now "Messages" resource (https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/messages.html#sending-a-message).

It's as easy as...

```
$response = $client->account->messages->create([
    'To'       => '+10000000000',
    'From'     => '+10000000000',
    'Body'     => $msg,
    'MediaUrl' => 'https://some.com/image.jpg'
]);

echo $response;
```